# Android Retrofit2 unable to get POST request working

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm unable to get POST http request to work. It seems like I'm not using retrofit2 library correctly, but from my research what I have should be working.

This is what my simplified object Class looks like:

```java
public class Tournament {
    private String name;
    private int nOfGames;
    private String game;
    private String userId;

    public Tournament(String name, int nOfGames, String game, String userId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nOfGames = nOfGames;
        this.game = game;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

I tried two approaches:

**approach 1:**

retrofit interface:

```java
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@POST("TournamentApi/")
Single<Tournament> createTournament(@Body Tournament tournament);
```

use:

```java
Tournament tournament = new Tournament(
        "some name",
        2,
        "some game",
        "1");

api.createTournament(tournament);
```

**approach 2:**

retrofit interface:

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("TournamentApi/")
public void insertTournament(
        @Field("Name") String name,
        @Field("NOfGames")  int nOfGames,
        @Field("Game") String game,
        @Field("UserId") String userId,
        Callback<Response> callback);
```

use:

```java
api.insertTournament(
        tournamentName.getText().toString(),
        Integer.parseInt(bestOfN.getText().toString()),
        gameName.getText().toString(),
        "1",
        new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
                String output = call.toString();
                String responze = response.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                String output = call.toString();
            }
        });
```

First approach doesn't do anything at all, no errors, nothing. I even tried using HttpLoggingInterceptor but nothing shows up at all. No requests are made it seems. Second approach crashes my app entirely because I get `No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)` error but I've seen other post same snippets without any annotation on callback that were supposedly working.

I also use retrofit2 for get requests which are working just fine, it's just post requests that I'm not able to get working.

Finally here is what works flawlessly (inserts entry into database) if I use it with Postman:

```
POST http://192.168.1.124:5001/api/TournamentApi
{
    "Name": "blabla_tournament",
    "NOfGames": 3,
    "Game": "some_game",
    "UserId": "5"
}
```

I would suspect it's something to do with localhost but since get requests are working just like they should be I'm pretty confident the issue is I'm using retrofit2 wrong.

Comment: What is the response from your API POST request?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@POST("TournamentApi")
Single createTournament(@Body Tournament tournament);`

`

Answer (score 0):

You must change : '
@Body Tournament tournament'
To :
'@Body JsonObject tournament'
That's will be work.